# Swift Programming an Attendance App

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift and mobile programming. I am attempting to make a classroom management app with one portion of the app tracking attendance.

I have a [DateTableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7vX6.png) full of date cells that segue to the [AttendanceTableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDIbI.png) containing cells of students and a view object that that you can tap to account for attendance. Obviously I would like for the attendance view objects to be reset with each new date cell that is picked, and persist for older dates in order to keep track of attendance. Is there any way to do this using the one UITableView that I have for the attendance list?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with Core Data. Does what you want

Comment: In theory, yes.  For details, you need to show what you're doing now and describe how you want it to be different.